# How is CoTaskMemAlloc() a replacement for SHGetMalloc()?

Tags: c++, winapi

In [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetmalloc#remarks), it is said that `CoTaskMemAlloc()` is a replacement for `SHGetMalloc()`.

However, those functions are using different parameter types and return value types.

So, how can the one be a replacement for the other?

Can someone please explain this?

I'm just trying to convert the old code for the new API and make sure it runs properly.

Comment: If you don't want to risk anything with an old existing code, you can keep it as is. They all point to the same functions underneath. In fact `SHGetMalloc` points to `CoGetMalloc` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cogetmalloc. `CoTaskMemAlloc(X)` => `CoGetMalloc(1, &alloc); alloc->Alloc(X); alloc->Release()` (Release is somewhat optional as it's a static per-process reference for perf reasons)

Comment: No, IMalloc::Alloc() uses the same parameter as CoTaskMemAlloc().  SHGetMalloc() was there to obtain the IMalloc implementation that Explorer used back in the olden days.  It no longer implements it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a drop-in replacement, in this case, "replacement for" means that you should now use `CoTaskMemAlloc` in places where you would have previously relied on `SHGetMalloc`.

Note that `SHGetMalloc` returns an allocator (which you would then presumably use), `CoTaskMemAlloc` obviates the need for that intermediate step, it is a much simpler call pattern.

Comment: So how do I convert the following `LPMALLOC pMalloc = NULL; SHGetMalloc( &pMalloc );`?

Comment: @Igor by simply eliminating `pMalloc` completely, as it is no longer needed. Replace all calls to `pMalloc->Alloc()` with `CoTaskMemAlloc()`, and all calls to `pMalloc->Free()` with `CoTaskMemFree()`.

Comment: OK,, thx. I will see if the code will work after full conversion... And what do I pass to that new functions?

Comment: @Igor You will be able to work this out by reading the documentation

Comment: @Igor `IMalloc::Alloc()` and `CoTaskMemAlloc()` take the same parameter, and return the same thing. `IMalloc::Free()` and `CoTaskMemFree()` take the same parameter. The `CoTaskMem...()` functions are drop-in replacements for the `IMalloc` class methods. You are simply removing the `IMalloc` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`CoTaskMemAlloc` is a replacement for `SHGetMalloc` in the sense that they are guaranteed to allocate from the same heap. The real replacement for `SHGetMalloc` is `CoGetMalloc` and `CoTaskMemAlloc` just calls `CoGetMalloc` internally.

SHAlloc/SHGetMalloc/SHFree exist because Windows 95 had a minimum RAM requirement of 4 MiB! To pull this off without paging to disk all the time shell32.dll implemented a mini version of COM to avoid loading ole32.dll into memory in Explorer.exe.

See also:

- [What's the difference between SHGetMalloc, SHAlloc, CoGetMalloc, and CoTaskMemAlloc](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040705-00/?p=38573)